# User specific rewrite rules

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config

I am developing a website that each user can point his domain to this website. while some of the resources are shared each user can design his own unique website using plugins, ...

I want to create rewrite rules specific for each user. these rules are unique per user but not necessarily in global.

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Products" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="products/(.+)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?id={R:1}" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

each user will have many rewriting rules each based on content of their own website. I can't just add all rules to one web.config file, right?

what can be done here?

Comment: If you allowed each user to write rules, couldn't they step on each other's urls? Its sounds like a very bad idea to me.

Comment: @developerwjk thats exactly why I'm trying to separate each users rules. I want to  to know how can I have separate rewrite rule files for each user. as I can have one separate rule file using configSource

Comment: So, are the users going to write their own rewrite rules? or are you trying to write a rewrite rule that will include user in the call to products.aspx?

Comment: @developerwjk user can specify menu captions (that are unique per user) and rewrite rules will be created programmatically. with configuration manager we can read/write settings to any web.config file we want. but is there a way to define (change default) a new web.config file?

Comment: in the other words I want user1.com use /user1.com/web.config and user2.com use /user2.com/web.config and ...